# Python concurrent.futures: threads don't start

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrent.futures

I made a program that starts 4 threads using concurrent.futures and sends a request to each website in a list.

Problem: It just doesn't start

```
import requests
import threading
import concurrent.futures

list=['amazon.com', 'google.com', 'youtube.com', 'microsoft.com']

def start(url):
    requests.get('https://'+url)
    print(line+' finished')

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    for url in list:
        executor.submit(start, url)
```

This on the other hand works:

```
import concurrent.futures

def start():
    print('lol')

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    for i in range(10):
        executor.submit(start)
```

Comment: print(line+' finished') - am i wrong or variable line is not defined here?

Comment: yes that is true, thank you. now it is working for this code BUT it doesn't show any error message. how can i change that?

Comment: If your code works properly it doesn't show any error, if you want to add message after every request you should write something like: print('{} finished'.format(url))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've just scheduled the tasks but you don't wait for the results and you have an error in your code (use of undefined variable) however the error message was "swallowed" by the context manager.

The [executor.submit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) method returns a [Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) object where you can get the return value by calling [result](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result) method:

```
import requests
import threading
import concurrent.futures

URLS = ['amazon.com', 'google.com', 'youtube.com', 'microsoft.com']


def start(url):
    requests.get('https://' + url)
    print(f'{url}: finished')


def main():
    futures = []

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        for url in URLS:
            futures.append(executor.submit(start, url))

        for future in futures:
            future.result()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```